# Unit managing in c++ class

Tags: c++

I am writing a class in c++ that does basic scientific calculations and measurements.
I have three member variables, value(double), uncertainty(double) and unit(string) and have overloaded operators such as +, -, /, and *.

```
Measurement operator+(const Measurement& m1, const Measurement& m2);
Measurement operator-(const Measurement& m1, const Measurement& m2);
Measurement operator*(const Measurement& m1, const Measurement& m2);
Measurement operator/(const Measurement& m1, const Measurement& m2);
```

which look like this:

```
Measurement operator+(const Measurement& m1, const Measurement& m2){
    if (m1.unit == m2.unit){
        double val = m1.value + m2.value;
        double uncert = (sqrt(pow(m1.uncertainty, 2)+pow(m2.uncertainty, 2)));
        string unit = m1.unit;
        return Measurement(val, uncert, unit);
    }throw invalid_argument("Units do not match!");
}
```

The rest of the operators also look similar with minor tweaks, and I get the value and uncertainty correctly, but I am struggling with multiplication and division of  units.
Let's say I have:

```
Measurement m_a(120.0, 3.0, "m");
Measurement m_b(20.0, 1.2, "sec");
Measurement m_c = m_a/m_b;
```

Now I want the unit of m_c to be "m sec^-1" and it should work for all such similar calculations involving multiplication or division of units.

My constructor takes two double and a string and correspondingly assigns them to the members.

Comment: your way of handling units is not type safe (because your units aren't types), there are libraries for working with units. That being said, your question is a bit unclear (what exactly is the question?) and a bit too broad

Comment: I am looking for a better way to handle my units, how do I keep a count of the power of the unit while keeping the parameter of constructor a string?

Comment: don't use strings for units, it can be done but it is extremely cumbersome. I cannot recommend you something specific, because I didn't use a library myself, but search for "C++ units" and you will find plenty

Comment: to get your specific question answered you need to clarify your question. There is no question here at the moment.

Comment: One such library is Boost [Units](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_units.html).  Also, the landing page to [LLNL/units](https://github.com/LLNL/units) has links to 9 other scientific units packages.

Comment: My question is how do I manage the power of the units when I multiply or divide two measurement instances. Let's say I have m3 = m1*m2, where m1's unit is "feet" and m2's unit is "sec^2 feet^-1". I need m3's unit to be "sec^2" as you can tell by the calculation.

Comment: Is there a way I can get around this by using maybe a map that keeps count of the unit's powers?

Comment: Please show what you tried, it is not quite clear what is the problem in doing something like `if (units == "sec" && unit.other == "sec") result.units = "sec^2";` (however, as already mentioned I would rather rethink the design fundamentally)

Comment: What you suggested works for identical and basic units, but when I start dealing with more complex units with multiple exponential value, that is when it starts getting difficult

Comment: What I came up is something like this: A function in which I can pass a string that just adds the unit string of the two instances, and then a map is created. So if I have the string = "feet^2 second^-1 feet^-3 second ^2", I get a map out of it, {feet : -1, second : 1}

Comment: "more complex units with multiple exponential value, that is when it starts getting difficult" thats what I am trying to tell you, you should use a library. If you want to write it yourself, not using strings but types will already make it much simpler. This is question is too broad

Comment: okay thanks, but I don't think the question allows for other libraries. I just made a function that might explain what I am trying to do better, I'll make a separate post.

Comment: you dont have to post another question, you can still edit this one

Answer (score 0):

Use a record like:

```
struct Unit {
    int meters;
    int seconds;
/*...*/
};
```

where each field represents the power of a certain basic unit. So e.g. for acceleration you will have meters=1, seconds=-2.